# UITabBarItem not active on app start

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have UITabBar controller

```
let tabBarController = UITabBarController()
tabBarController.viewControllers = [todayViewController, forecastViewController]
window.rootViewController = tabBarController
window.makeKeyAndVisible()
tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0
```

inside `todayViewController`:

```
tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Today", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "TodayTabBarItem"), selectedImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "SunTabBarItemSelected"))
```

inside `forecastViewController`:

```
tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Forecast", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ForecastTabBarItem"), selectedImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ForecastTabBarItemSelected"))
```

When I start the app `UITabBarItem` of the first view controller is inactive. When I tap on it or on another one it becomes active (highlighted text and right image)

What should I do to make `UITabBarItem` active on app start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try tabBarItem = UITabBarItem not during the call to viewDidLoad, but when creating ViewContrller - in init